# How do you input the voltage signal to an oscilloscope?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope

I was watching this tutorial on "analyzing actual Ethernet encoding"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8CmibhvZ0c&ab_channel=BenEater

[image]

Orange pair is transmitting data to the oscilloscope and the green pair is receiving data to the right. This oscilloscope measures the voltage across the two wires of the orange pair and plots that voltage over time on the graph.

[image]

Using Manchester coding, he's decoded 16 bits. The first byte is 75 (K), the second is 65 (A).

My question is, how did he input "K" and "A" in the first place, which then shows up on the oscilloscope? Is it as simple as typing "K" and "A" on the keyboard? I want to know this so that I can replicate this experiment by myself should I wish to.

Thanks!

Comment: That  guy in the video totally missed the initial frame alignment at the beginning of byte decoding. 75 and 65 is totally nonsense, the bit sequence could be shifted left or right by any length. Decoding Ethernet packets is more complicated than this. BTW I could also argue against shorting one of the balanced data in the pair with the scope ground.

Comment: @carloc Yes, that is true, but this video is about decoding the bits. The preamble is discussed in the next video which is about Ethernet frames. And while shorting scope ground with the balanced data is not exactly right, the wire pair still floats and thus this is possible.

Comment: @Justme I see your point but, decoding 8 random bits starting from anywhere is nonsense. So at least it would be better to swap or merge video 1 and 2 topics. And the pairs are not floating, there's a center tap 75 ohm common mode termination to ground, for sure scope can be connected like in the video without damaging anything but at worst the datalink. What I find really bad on both topics  is do-not-tell while supposing to be tutoring.

Comment: @carloc I have to agree, those are not necessarily bytes, just bits that might be decoded starting from a random starting point - again, good enough for illustration purposes, it is a quick gentle tutorial into the subject how it works. And you are simply wrong about how the wire pairs work, the center tap is not DC terminated into any potential, it is only AC terminated, so grounding one wire of the pair has very little effect. That is why Ethernet has the transformer to begin with, it's an isolated interface.

Comment: @Justme I feel you involved, are you the video author? I didn't really mean to be rude with him, just pointing out how difficult is to explain something, making it simple and clear to beginners but at the same time avoiding plain mistakes. This is bad because while for a skilled reader is easy to tell those mistakes apart they may become part of the "knowledge" of the beginner.  For the pairs I am not wrong, surely they are only AC terminated but we happen to have a 10MHz signal which is I guess AC, isn't it?

Comment: No, I am not the author. I just don't understand why you think it is garbage unless it explains all at once for beginners, instead of going one small step at a time. For the 10MHz signal pair, since it is floating, the scope clip will set the one wire to 0V scope earth potential, and the other wire will then be +/- 800mV or so around it. Just like without the scope, one wire would have +/- 800mV compared to the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122889/discussion-between-carloc-and-justme).

Comment: I think I've already pointed it out but I'll try to rephrase. It's garbage because it doesn't simplyfy the topic for teaching it in small steps. Trying to do so it instead states wrong concepts which will be later difficult to remove. Doing this tutoring in the right way -simplify without stating wrong concepts- is indeed a difficult task but if the video author cannot do it he'd better not post anything at all. I don't have anything against that video particularly, it's just one more so-so tutorial not needed by anybody, some more noise on the web.

Comment: To clarify: you are asking how the person made the computer transmit an Ethernet signal that had the letters "K" and "A" in it? Your question has nothing to do with oscilloscopes or voltages?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/559588/31097, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/138796/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67038861/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that he has a program that sends that key sequence continuously while he adjusts his test setup to capture it correctly.

That's not just a keyboard, it is a computer.  He has a program running that is sending those characters through the network port.  This involves about a dozen layers of hardware and software, such as the PHY (physical layer) and MAC (Media Access Controller), both of which reside on the NIC (Network Interface Controller).  Software takes the code for a keypress coming from the keyboard interface, converts it to ASCII, sends it to more software such as the "IP stack".  The entire system seems bizarrely complex at first, but each layer of the onion was added for a reason.

Here is a description of a protocol stack, to give you a taste of what's going on in there.

https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/

Answer (score 1):

The decoded data can be anything. It is really for illustrational purposes only.

You can send Ethernet packets in many ways.

There is also a good chance that the computer sends all kinds of packets every now and then, but if it doesn't, you can use ping command or whatever program you wish to trigger packets being sent out.

Since you specifically want to send an Ethernet packet triggered by keyboard, you need a terminal program. And some target server to talk to. Unless you want to send UDP packets. There are terminal programs that can send UDP packets too.